# Set value button programmatically

Tags: c#, html

If I had 100 buttons I want to set text = "Save" and the id is an auto number like saveButton_1, saveButton_2 what the best way to do it? The button isn't dynamic generated can be accessed via code behind.

Current I do it like this but seem to long.

```
saveButton_1.value = saveButton_2.value ... till 100 = "Save"
```

Comment: Could you please add clarifications for : How do you generate those buttons? is that from the back-end? is all are `asp:button` ?

Comment: not asp:button  but normal html button with added runat="server"

Comment: If you are able to use Jquery then just need to add class to every button and using Jquery find this class like $(".className") and apply value to text to button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding a bit @Adil 's answer, if you have your buttons within a container you can get them using the HtmlButton type

```
IEnumerable< HtmlButton> btns = buttonContainer.Controls.OfType<HtmlButton>();

if(btns != null)
{
     //get only the ones that have a special class to know which ones you need to update
     var btnList = btns.Where(x => x.Attributes["class"] == "save-button");

     //update the text for all that passed the filter
     foreach(HtmlButton ctrl in btnList)
     {
        ctrl.InnerText = "Save Me";
     }
}
```

Html

```
<div id="buttonContainer" runat="server">
    <button id="save1" type="button" class="save-button"  runat="server">save 1</button>
    <button id="save2" type="button" class="save-button" runat="server">save 1</button>
    <button id="save3" type="button" class="save-button" runat="server">save 1</button>
    <button id="save4" type="button" class="save-button" runat="server">save 1</button>
    <button id="save5" type="button" runat="server">not save</button>
    <button id="save6" type="button" class="save-button" runat="server">save 1</button>
    <button id="save7" type="button" class="save-button" runat="server">save 1</button>
    <button id="save8" type="button" class="save-button" runat="server">save 1</button>
    <button id="save9" type="button" class="save-button" runat="server">save 1</button>
</div>
```

[image]

If you don't have the button on the same container then you  will need to loop through the controls you have in order get to the proper htmlbuttons

Comment: need to remove this . How ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        btn.Text = "Save";
    }
```

Comment: Your type button means asp button but not html button, also, there might be another buttons not doing "save" function

Comment: I would recommend you to use JQuery

Comment: But this is all  button which not preferable..  only need to use certain button

Comment: Adil . yes i thinking of JQUERY to loop   but need to know how C# work .

Comment: Try something like this Button myButton;
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            myButton = (Button)FindControl("saveButton_" + i);
            myButton.Text = "Save";